How can I push back on my co-worker's changes that I disagree with?
I'm co-founding a business with 2 other people, and no employees. One of them is another experienced software engineer like me, and the third can code but is much less experienced. Unfortunately, I've found a number of the experienced software engineer's pull-requests (PRs) to be very misguided. Often I find that things are done in the name of performance in his PRs without actually helping performance or having measurements behind them. Here are the last 3 conflicts we've had, which covers most of his recent work:

He wrote a CSV parser from scratch rather than using the well-established Rust CSV parsing library, in an effort to make things faster (it did not make things faster, and had bugs)
He wrote a 3,000 line PR for me to review, with a fair portion of that PR dedicated to supporting a file format that would supposedly parse faster. However, it actually took 20x longer to parse than our existing supported file formats, when he finally measured it during PR review
He significantly refactored a change I'd written without actually understanding how it worked in the first place, again in the name of performance without actually helping. According to him, it will help in the future, although when and to what extent it will help is not clear, and right now we're struggling just to launch our MVP.

I don't mind, to some extent, that he's done these things. People do silly things, and I'm not perfect either. However, the biggest issue for me is that when I raise concerns about these changes, he gets hostile. He comes to me with these changes as PRs, meaning he's already invested a bunch of time and effort into them before I become aware of them. We end up in a meeting with the other co-founder (to try to gain consensus and get his input too) where the experienced engineer has a tendency to yell and swear. Part of the reason for the hostility, I think, is that I'm pushing back on these changes after they're in the PR stage. I don't like telling him that something he's spent a bunch of time on should be changed, but I don't think the changes he's making are reasonable. He was a principal engineer at his previous company, and I think he considers it his prerogative to design things entirely on his own, without talking about what he's going to do/is doing.
He also says the implementer should be allowed to decide what to do on the stuff they've been tasked with, so I shouldn't push back. Now I know there's a certain amount of leeway given to the person who's making changes to decide for themselves what makes sense, but I think that his changes can be very unreasonable, and we shouldn't just allow him to push them through.
Does anyone have any thoughts on what to do here? I want to avoid this pattern and not end up with both his problematic changes in the code base, and these hostile meetings.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'll say it: You probably need to leave this business startup.
As per your description this person has poor judgement, can't coordinate with others, is arrogant, gets defensive, yells and screams, and repeatedly makes the rookie error of premature optimization. In my experience, people like that don't get better and can't be managed. Like a bad code smell, they will keep generating problems as long as they're around.
Do you really want to spend the entirety of your time at this business fighting these battles nonstop? That's almost certainly the prospect you're facing. I recommend you take the hint and get out before you lose more time and energy.

"In my experience, people like that don't get better and can't be managed." This. If he is an "experienced software engineer" and made it all the way to "principal engineer" at his previous company, it means that he has already had lots of opportunities to learn basic software engineering principles. If, after all those years, he still does not understand them, it's highly unlikely that a few more years will miraculously change that.

"You probably need to leave..." or he does.

Excuse me, there was no “premature optimisation”. His code was 20 times slower. 20 faster, I don’t mind much (usually) if it’s premature.

It doesn't make sense to spend time optimizing for performance until there is a REASONABLE known need. What OP is saying is wasting time rather than adding features. There is no good way for this to end well. I rarely suggest people to leave a company. This is a case that it is clear to get out. Working with someone that doesn't grasp priority, engineering, or basic business is a plan for failure. Painful at that.

@gnasher729 hehe, we've finally found the real root of all evil: "premature pessimization".

Why is it that OP needs to leave instead of that person? Obviously, OP can't force the person to give up their contributions, but there's gotta be some room for negotiations.

@PasserBy - Because the third person didn't shut the outlandish behaving person. For a founder / manager that is the same as agreeing with them. It is effectively 2 against 1.  Getting rid of offending person leaves OP with a weak partner. Start ups sure don't need weak or poor behaving partnets. Steelers Wheel has a fine song about a similar situation. If OP has a decent lawyer, maybe  they can start a separate company with the same or similar IP. This company is going to flounder without major change in behavior.

The issue shouldn't be whether you agree. It should be whether the work is necessary, sufficient, efficient, and maintainable. It sounds like the part you are having trouble with is defining what is necessary.
The simplest solution to that is project management tools. Not just source control, but prioritized task lists, and planning meetings where you discuss proposals and set priorities and/or consider alternatives before significant effort is invested in something that doesn't have consensus.
And require commits to pass tests, both regression and new function, including performance, before being accepted into main.
Give yourselves a chance to focus properly before defensiveness can become an issue. And give people a chance to say "well, that didn't work as planned" before bringing in others.
If someone wants to do something not in the priority queue, they should understand that there is no guarantee that it will be accepted. The important thing is that this is agreed to up front.

I think that's a good idea, to emphasize project management tools, assuming I can get his buy-in. I do think conflicts can still arise. For instance, for the CSV parser, he might argue that it's a necessary part of the "support reading from that one data source that uses CSV" task.

That justifies having a CSV parser. It doesn't necessarily justify it writing one. Always ask if off-the-shelf functionality is available; if it is ask why that is not sufficient. If he has a good reason for doing something different, that's one thing. If he doesn't, go with the standard solution and put writing the alternative as a experiment to be performed at very low priority when time permits. Very few people really want to reinvent standard wheels; if there is something special about this one it may or may not be worthwhile but it needs to be discussed.

Projekt management tools will not help here. This is about people disagreeing about how things should be done, not about people disagreeing what should be done first.

I am with toolforger here. If there is a Team and one member thinks of himself as the only member (that counts), then no tool will help. In a bigger company, a higher-up, manager or something of that sort could fix the situation (one way or the highway) through authority - but in a startup, where 3 people are supposed to have equal say? No chance.

@Fildor: The tool provides a starting point for discussion. It may not be enough to fix the problem. It should be enough to make clear what the problem is and where it lies. Given that the only alternatives are to either live with it or leave, and given that the original poster has indicated they don't want to leave, I recommend trying this one first. If you have a better solution, please post your own answer; I might upvote it.

@toolforger: the tool will encourage discussion before the individual goes hearing off in their own direction. This should at least be enough to discourage needless reinvention of wheels. Such as the CSV case. I am not claiming it is a complete solution; I think it is the best step available toward improving the situation as it now exists. Again, if you have a better solution, please post your own answer.

Well, the solution that's in my mind has been proposed enough here. Not knowing the exact situation also makes it hard to say anything definitively. We only have one side to the story. It just sounds to me like that would be a waste of time. Given the behavior of that guy (again: taking OP's account for fact). Trying to suggest a tool might still be worth it, not denying that. Just my hopes are not very high.

work being necessary falls back to them agreeing that it is necessary or not so essentially that differentiation feels hollow, BUT I agree with prioritizing and deciding before implementing. You might highlight that in particular more over the other part.  The tools then are only a materialization of the process to first decide and then do (i.e. just installing them and not using them properly indeed they wouldn't help, but that then would be pretty passive aggressive^^). Perhaps making that clear would make it more agreeable to people so focused on whether the tools in themselves help.

There is no technical tool to fix a people problem.


I'm co-founding a business with 2 other people


He wrote a CSV parser from scratch


Does anyone have any thoughts on what to do here?

It makes no sense to continue business with this person.  Even if the CSV parser was a million times better, it should not be rewritten as the three of you do not have time to waste on such trivial things.
You have to bring a product to market, and your goal should be a MVP ("Minimal Viable Product").  Writing things from scratch, and doing things in the name of performance is not the way time should be spent.
Get an MVP out the door to see even if it means using hand written index cards rather than writing a database application.


Part of the reason for the hostility, I think, is that I'm pushing back on these changes after they're in the PR stage. I don't like telling him that something he's spent a bunch of time on should be changed, but I don't think the changes he's making are reasonable. He was a principal engineer at his previous company, and I think he considers it his prerogative to design things entirely on his own, without talking about what he's going to do/is doing.


He also says the implementer should be allowed to decide what to do on the stuff they've been tasked with, so I shouldn't push back. Now I know there's a certain amount of leeway given to the person who's making changes to decide for themselves what makes sense, but I think that his changes can be very unreasonable, and we shouldn't just allow him to push them through.

I think all of the issue is found in these two paragraphs.
Yes, if you're going to challenge something, then challenging it after it's already written is not the best habit to be in. This alone could explain the fury.
The other side of this coin though, is that there are significant overheads to discussing design (and resolving disagreement) compared to an individual getting on with it.
Discussion can result in higher quality, but it can also result in "too many chiefs" or "design by committee", especially when there are complicated judgments without decisive answers, or when what is at stake is not a single severable decision but the need for a set of decisions to integrate together properly or achieve an aesthetic quality.
Some (in fact very many) developers do not have the communication skills and experience to engage in design discussions, and if they do, then the time and effort of discussions is still a form of work which will compete with the time and effort they would otherwise allocate to performing the design themselves.
The fact that some of his activities or decisions have not turned out well, doesn't necessarily mean he's taking the wrong approach in general. As you say, mistakes can be made, and sometimes mistakes only become apparent in hindsight.
On the other hand, if many mistakes are made, then there might be an issue of competence (in which case why are you working with the guy?), of the excessive pace of work (which won't be helped by having more discussion on top), or of intrinsic difficulty and unfamiliarity of the problems (which may or may not be helped in the end by your involvement, but will by definition not be simple to discuss).
Conclusion
I think what you have to do is establish a theme which shows that poor decisions are being made and that he should know they are poor decisions at the outset, or that you would have known at the outset if you knew that work was afoot and that it is seriously worthwhile having collective design discussions in future.
There's a risk, though, that you start arguing about personal policies, or about conflicting experiences in your own backgrounds which guide you to different judgments.
The mere fact that many mistakes are discovered doesn't mean poor decisions are being made at the outset - who knew what the performance of the parser would be before it was written?
Also, more discussion is not a solution unless you can afford more time and effort for it and a slower pace of progress. It might be worth having code that is 20 times slower, rather than a development process that is 20 times slower because everything gets scrutinised and haggled over.
I think if talk about the issue so far is already provoking furious exchanges, then you might have to consider whether you either want to put up with the status quo which is hobbling along, or whether there are irreconcilable differences and the viability of the business is at stake over them.
There's often no magic wand, and these speculative business ventures fail often precisely because they are ventures that most would consider foolhardy - they embark on non-trivial and experimental development activity, and normal development management problems are compounded with the financial pressures of a business which is non-viable unless the development succeeds.
The risks and arduousness of the path are what form the barriers to entry, which allow superprofits to be made in the occasional cases of success.

Multiple options.
In descending order of desirability:
Solve the interpersonal situation
This sounds like a company with two senior devs not having enough respect for each other's workstyle.
This does not mean that you're wrong with your criticism of his workstyle; a 3000-LoC is in fact a bad idea unless and until PRs typically fly through without significant changes, which they typically don't even with superhuman coding skills.
Of course, you may have your own quirks and problems in your workstyle. Humans being what they are, it's quite likely that you underestimate what you contribute to the problem, even if you are aware that this might be the case.
The first thing you need is somebody whom you both respect about people problems, and who is able to communicate about people problems effectively.
It's unlikely that you can be such a person for him, otherwise the situation wouldn't have gotten to the point you describe and you wouldn't be asking for help.
Try to find a mediator. In Europe there are even professionals that offer this service, but anybody with really good people skills can do this.
Work within the given constraints
You know why the company has two seniors: You can't do your own work plus his, so having him in is a net win.
Don't fret that he could be doing so much more if he were just more disciplined; work with what you have, make the maximum use of it, and move on.
Remember that your role is to support the company in its current phase. Anything you build now will likely need to be ripped anyway as soon as the business starts to grow, because growth will change the requirements.
You can't plan for these changes anyway!
For an extreme example, recall that the blocky appearance of the Minecraft was supposed to be a temporary solution but became its recognizable signature. It won't happen to your project in this way, but to some extent, all software needs to evolve into multiple directions.
Actually, I found that being overly perfect tends to make the software less flexible because it is too well-adapted to the requirements that you had in mind when building it.
You can still try to improve him, but don't try to improve more than one thing at a time. Changing work styles is hard, working on more than one aspect of this can quickly overburden a person and antagonize them (and I guess you are already in that situation).
Be prepared for the situation that he does not accept even small improvement. Work with what you have.
Bad code is not the end of the world.
If the quality and performance issues are not life-threatening for the company, his contribution is a net plus: If the company survives, there will be enough budget to redo stuff that turns out to be bad.
I agree it would be better if your peer had better code quality.
But life isn't all roses, and unless the quality isn't life-threatening, fighting over code quality is going to cost more time and effort than what the quality issues will cost.
You're a three-person team. You cannot afford to spend time on fights, you need to get stuff working!
Note that this is not an option if the quality issues do threaten the life of the company.
Also note that you may be part of the problem yourself.
If you can, find out what he dislikes about your code. Find out what parts of that criticism can affect the company's success, and change these.
Get out
If none of the other options work,the company is doomed to fail.
Leave. Find something else to do.

"If none of the other options work,the company is doomed to fail." - If that's a software company it is doomed to fail. Look at the statistics. Barely any do make it anyway. -- Just to say bailing out wouldn't be a disgrace but rather a "lesson learned".

Code quality is irrelevant if the coworker is wasting time building stuff to solve problems that have already been solved.

@Fildor true. But also: Look at those that made it, barely any had really healthy starts... and most generate terrible code at the beginning that they later have to dig deep into to stabilize their product after their initial success.

@PeterM even if he's reinventing the wheel, it has a net value. After all, learning an existing solution takes time, getting used to its quirks, it's Dos and Don'ts takes time, and these times don't exist if you do a handcrafted solution. The one reason why it's still usually a net loss is that handcrafted software tends to have more bugs, but even then: Do you prefer a CSV parser that (barely) does its job, or no CSV parser at all?

@toolforger CSV parsers are deceptively complex.  There are a large number of corner cases that you have to take into account.  But they are a solved problem with very good libraries in every language.  These libraries are produced by people whose core mission is to build CSV parsers.  But if your core mission is not building CSV parsers, then building them is a stupid waste of time.  And if you're capable of building a CSV parser, then you're also capable of learning how to use a 3rd party library with little effort - and in far less time than building your own solution.

@PeterM sure, but that does not take away that a self-written library is better-known than an external one. Besides, the CSV parser for a specific purpose does not really have to deal with all the corner cases. I agree it's not necessary to write one, and usually more work, but if you throw in the time to persuade the guy who wants to write it, and the follow-up misgivings for being overruled, it's still not a net win to shut his efforts down.

Sounds like you have two people pulling on the same rope ... but in different directions. What to do?
First, you two should agree about the kind of software you write here. Is it an MVP, to test the market and iterate rapidly towards a viable product? Or is it the perfect software that will, on day 1, amaze everyone with the speed of its CSV parsing, but will take 3 times as long to meet the market? What's the big risk for your startup? That you won't manage to parse CSV at decent speed? Or that you build the wrong product?
If you can get such an agreement, put it in writing, and point to it whenever he wastes effort on things that do not advance the MVP. That is, if he is touchy if the perfection of his code is challenged, challenging his goals instead may bypass the touchyness and get your point across in a way that respects his engineering expertise.
If however you can't get such an agreement ... if the founding team is unable to communicate and rally behind a shared vision, electing to throw temper tantrums instead ... then it may be time to leave, because you are more likely to succeed in a different team. In that case, be sure to ask about willingness to prototype when interviewing your next engineering lead.
